# How to set dynamically the correct Dateformat in VB for SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, date-format

Hello i have an sql query which uses a Dateformat. This code will run on different servers but every server have different dateformats. sometimes yyyy-MM-dd and sometimes yyyy-dd-MM.
I tried to read the userlanguage to choose the correct query. but it doesnt work properly. 
Do you know any other good solution to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance

```
 Dim Systemsprache as String 
 Systemsprache = Request.UserLanguages(0)
 If String.Compare(Systemsprache, "de-DE") = 0 Then
                sqlcmd = "SELECT convert(varchar(8) , [VON],108) as [VON]  ,convert(varchar(8) , [BIS],108) as [BIS] FROM [RESERVIERUNGRAUM]  where RAUM_ID =" + hCurrRaumID.Value + " and VON >='" + Date.Parse(wiDateVON1.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and BIS <'" + Date.Parse(wiDateVON1.Value).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"

            Else
                sqlcmd = "SELECT convert(varchar(8) , [VON],108) as [VON]  ,convert(varchar(8) , [BIS],108) as [BIS] FROM [RESERVIERUNGRAUM]  where RAUM_ID =" + hCurrRaumID.Value + " and VON >='" + Date.Parse(wiDateVON1.Value).ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") + "' and BIS <'" + Date.Parse(wiDateVON1.Value).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") + "'"
            End If
```

Comment: What is the data type of your column in the database?  Are you storing dates as strings?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, you can use the universal format '#yyyy-mm-dd#' regardless of the server default date format.

Comment: +1 This is the way I use it for my dates in all .NET applications, works a treat.

Comment: No, you can compare a date constant like this directly with a date field. Microsoft make a different suggestion here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx